# EF4 Database First Model Design based on properly normalized table

Tags: asp.net, entity

I have created a Conceptual Model in my project using a table in my database.  This table is related to a few other tables in the database which I will not be creating models for in project (tables are large and were designed for another app).  Instead, my DBA has created some stored procedures for me to use that will return the related data I need from those tables (using Complex Types).

The Conceptual Model has three properties that are mapped to three ID columns in the table (FKs of related tables).  In the View of my project, I am binding the model to a gridview, so the field values with IDs are not very useful.  To that end, I added the stored procedures mentioned above and imported the functions to Complex Types and then added Complex Type Properties to the Model for each Complex Type.  This didn't work.  I kept getting Error 3004: Problem in mapping fragments...where the Complex Type properties where not mapped to a value in the model.

Here is an example of my table with one of the Complex Type Properties:

DisplayID
StoreID = StoreID, StoreName, StoreLocation **
OrderID
ProductID
DisplayLocation
DisplaySize

** The StoreID being the Complex Property Type and the StoreID, StoreName, StoreLocation makeup the ComplexType; I map the StoreID of the Complex Type to the StoreID of the table in the database.

My scenario above does not really fit the examples I've seen of adding Complex Property Types.  Examples I've seen are like below:

DisplayID
Store = StoreName, StoreLocation
Order
Product
DisplayLocation
DisplaySize

Do I need to change the table structure in the database like the example immediately above?  Should I create tables in the database for each of the Complex Types instead?  Need to know why so I can convince my DBA to use the columns I need instead of the ID columns and to create new tables in lieu of the stored procedures he created for me.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you are trying to map a navigation property "StoreID" into the complex type which is not supported (see [Complex Type documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738472.aspx)). Complex types is really grouping of scalar properties from your entity (or you can map them to your stored procedure o/p & then they can be used on *stand-alone* basis).

I will suggest that you use views instead of stored procedures to get the data (and use views in same way as you will use table in entity model - so `store` will be an view). I beleive that it would be easy to convince your DBA for views rather than direct access to tables.

Comment: Yes. I felt like I was sticking a round peg into a square...it fits but not meant to be. My DBA had also offered to make views in lieu of the sprocs; going to take him up on that.  Sooo....how about the main table? Do you think ID columns need to be changed to reflect the views; ie StoreID => Store?  Or do I leave them be and use navigation properties in conjunction with the views?

Comment: @Rich, once you have views, you can use navigation properties. Complex types can be used to group attributes (if needed) - for example, address. In your case, `Store` will a first class entity (mapped to the view).

Comment: I got my DBA to create views (instead of the using sprocs with Complex Types) and mapped to the views by creating the appropriate associations and navigation properties.  This is a bit tricky though; I had several compile errors but finally figured it out.  For anyone else that may have a similar scenario be sure to set your associations properly by deleting the FK in the primary table and setting the appropriate cardinality between the two entities. Once thats done, be sure to set the Navigation Property to the appropriate Association. Thanks Vinay!